# Does .replace not work in a for loop?

Tags: javascript

So I'm trying to just make a ".replace" loop, but something mysterious is happening.

```
var cell = "r1c1";

for (i = 0; i <= 4; i++){
  cell = cell.replace(cell[3],i+1);
```

My expected output:

```
cell = "r1c1"
cell = "r1c2"
cell = "r1c3"
cell = "r1c4"
cell = "r1c5"
```

The actual output:

```
cell = "r1c2"
cell = "r2c1"
cell = "r2c3"
cell = "r2c4"
cell = "r2c5"
```

As you can see, it runs normal EXCEPT for the second iteration.
What in the world am I doing so wrong?

Comment: Hmm... The actual output is `r1c1, r2c1, r2c3, r2c4, r2c5`.

Comment: @Teemu Thanks! I've edited it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't like this, but the fix I ended up using looks like this:

`cell = "r"+(j)+cell.substr(2,2);`

Since I'm inevitably answering my own question, here, I still want to ask for comments:

How elegant would you say a solution like this is in the long run?

Answer (score 5):

`cell.replace(cell[3], i+1)` is going to replace the first instance of the '1' character it finds in the string 'r1c1'. In this case it is the '1' at position 1 that gets replaced instead of the '1' at position 3.

To get the results you want, try

```
var cell = "r1c1";

for (i = 0; i <= 4; i++){
  cell = cell.substring(0, cell.length-1)+(i+1);
}
```

Comment: That's very helpful!
Now how would I iterate this, so it could change r's number once after every 5 changes in c?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression: `/^r(\d+)c(\d+)/`:

```
var row_col = 'r1c1';
var match = /^r(\d+)c(\d+)/.exec(row_col);  // match string
var row = +match[1];  // extract row
var col = +match[2];  // extract column
// edit row and col as needed
row_col = 'r' + row + 'c' + col;  // "reassemble" string
```

This will take care of bigger row/column numbers than 9. If that is not to be expected, then read about [String.prototype.substring()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring):

```
var row_col = 'r1c1';
var row = +row_col.substring(1,2);
var col = +row_col.substring(3,4)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
Now, would I be right to assume `substring()` and `substr()` are _not_ the same function?

Comment: @MarkPuchalaII, yes, this not same function, difference in parameters